# Partial template specialization over instantiated and uninstantiated template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I have the following two structs:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct one { /* ... */ };

template<template<typename...> typename T>
struct two { /* ... */ };
```

When I have example instantiated/uninstantiated templates like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct sample_templated { /* ... */ };

using instantiated = sample_templated<double>;
```

then I can do

```cpp
one<instantiated>{};
two<sample_templated>{};
```

just fine. I would like to merge the definition of `one` and `two` such that they have the same name, though, as this would allow recursion.

I tried having a default definition like

```cpp
template<typename...>
struct types_match_impl;
```

and having the two original structs be partial specializations of this, but this is incompatible with `two`.

What is the solution here?

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you want, but I am guessing you want to pass `types_match_impl` to itself. Can you show the code you would like to write, and describe what you think it should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The way you're hoping for is not possible.** Here's why:

```
one<instantiated>{};
two<sample_templated>{};
```

`one` "uses" more than `two`: It is referring to `instantiated` which is `sample_templated` *instantiated with* `double`. `two` on the other hand is only "using" the `sample_templated`.

When you think of templates as functions on types, then this becomes even clearer: `two` is a function which accepts a (type-level) function to create some type. `one` is a function which accepts a type to create some type:

```
one :: T -> one<T>
two :: (T -> U) -> two<(T -> U)>
```

Put differently the parameter of `one` has a different "kind" ("type of type") as the one of `two`.

**What you can do:**

- You can provide a specialization of `one` which accepts a template template parameter ("type level function") *and* the template parameter for that:

  ```
  template<template<typename...> typename TT, typename T>
  struct one<TT<T>>  { /* ... */ }; // this basically "calls" TT
  ```
- You can turn `two` into something which can accept both, albeit with a "dummy" template template parameter:

  ```
  template<template<typename...> typename TT, typename... Ts>
  struct two { /* */ };

  template<typename...>
  struct Void;

  template<typename T>
  struct two<Void<>, T> { /* Use T like in one */ };
  // or derive from one<T>
  ```

There are probably more approaches, but these will depend on your specific use case.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. The solution looks promising, I'll get back with my results (PS: love the Haskell thrown in :) )

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to have both "kinds" of types in the same variadic parameter pack, so recursion as I have imagined it, is not possible

Comment: It turns out that for my design I don't even need uninstanciated templates, but this information will be helpful for the future